# Existing element can't be found by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried to find an element in a page by its id and xpath, but in every case I got the same error message back. I also tried to find the element by the text displayed using the code below, but the problem persisted:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Uma ou mais sondas DP')]")
```

I made sure to wait until the page was fully loaded before trying to find the elements.

Any ideas or suggestions on what could be causing this issue?

This is the repository link to access the source code: https://github.com/LucasC97/HTML-Source-Code

[The element I'm trying to find with Selenium is this one (I could only find it using the Inspector from Firefox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuPT7.png)

[Error by ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPAZ1.png)

[Error by XPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOI08.png)

Edit: As I mentioned in the comment section, the element is inside an iframe, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D22E1.png). However I got a TimeoutException trying to use the following code before the find_element command, as suggested:

```
iframe=WebDriverWait(driver,  10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe")))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

I tried to use the *find_elements_by_tag_name* method to find the iframe elements in the source code, but it returned an empty list.

Comment: please share at least the url

Comment: The complete source code of the page you mean?

Comment: yeah or just a link to it, is easier

Comment: Is it inside any iframe ?

Comment: @Timeler I would send the link of the page but to get to log in to the website and access this particular page you have to get a paid subscription. I just edited the added the source code to github and put the link in the description of the question.

Comment: @PDHide Yes, I just checked it out and it is inside an iframe. How does that affect the ability of the method of finding an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iframe=WebDriverWait(driver,  10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe")))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_id("WFD6")


#REMAINING CODE TO INTERACT WITH ELEMENTS INISIDE IFRAME

#once done exit from iframe

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

You have to switch to iframe first to interact with elements inside that ,

Then switch back to interact with elements outside the iframe

Comment: I tried to use the method you suggested but it unfortunately didn't work. I'm having a hard time trying to understand what is going on. I know that there is are iframe elements in the source code and that one of them contain the element I'm trying to find using Selenium, but for some reason Selenium also can't find any iframe elements. I updated the description of the question to add this information.

Comment: @LucasCruz is the element inside , iframe and add the html of the iframe also

Comment: I finally managed to find the element I wanted to, the problem was that it was nested inside multiple frames. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.lsTextView[ct='TV'][title='Nome']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "span[@ct='TV' and @title='Nome'][starts-with(., 'Uma ou mais sondas DP')]")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.lsTextView[ct='TV'][title='Nome']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "span[@ct='TV' and @title='Nome'][starts-with(., 'Uma ou mais sondas DP')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)